# Separate column names with variable and year

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape

I am working with a data set from UNCTAD Eora database (https://worldmrio.com/unctadgvc/Database_GVC_2018update_rev0323.csv)
It provides the main indicators from the data bank.
Unfortunately, the dataset covering 5 indicators for the years 1990-2018 for a set of countries  contains 147 variavles, because the **variable name contain the year and the indicator**: e.g. DVX1990, DVX1991,... ,VA_exp1990, VA_exp1991. The variable names are **not separated by a space or any other separator**. The numbers directly follow the letters.

```
head(SADC_DVX_VAexp)
           V1    DVX1990    DVX1991    DVX1992    DVX1993    DVX1994
1:     Angola 416258.300 446696.900 597805.100 499129.600 655503.900
2:   Botswana  56364.310  54098.040  58326.030  58459.560  64559.360
3:   DR Congo 236784.500 192829.600 191504.100 178502.700 198157.000
4:    Lesotho   6222.682   5691.562   7669.519   8340.936   8990.118
5: Madagascar  79830.220  79074.500  91451.380  95090.820 110577.600
6:     Malawi  51759.320  57607.130  56463.370  50866.980  50288.080

VA_exp1990 VA_exp1991 VA_exp1992 VA_exp1993 VA_exp1994 VA_exp1995
1: 1258915.00 1392318.00 1870753.00 1608752.00 2085250.00 1521991.00
2:  247510.00  247904.60  260424.40  245404.40  259269.50  303265.70
3:  417597.40  330625.30  316347.40  291127.50  317557.20  395383.60
4:   63759.54   59936.89   68551.54   59214.12   54261.97   55090.95
5:  325254.90  320890.60  370122.30  395407.80  456894.60  541780.80
6:  205316.70  244511.70  233732.50  210306.90  217603.90  255140.10
```

I would like to transform the wide data set into a long data set that looks like this

```
         V1    Year    DVX    VA_exp    FVA    GVC     DVA
1:   Angola    1990    value  value     value  value   value
2:   Angola    1991    value  value     value  value   value
3:   Angola    1992    value  value     value  value   value
4:    ...       ...    value  value     value  value   value
5:   Botswana  1990    value  value     value  value   value
6:   Botswana  1991    value  value     value  value   value
```

However, the functions that I have discovered so far, either work with each variable separately, and/or separate the names only when they have spaces or separators within the name. I guess I need to apply something that separates the **last** four digits from the column name but I am not sure with which function.

I would be greatful for any recommendations!

This is my code so far

```
# install packages
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# load the data ----------------------------------------------------

# set working directory
setwd("XXX")

# load cvs data into R
my_path <- file.path("Database_GVC_2018update_rev0323_Main indicators by country.csv")
DVX_VAexp <- fread(my_path)

# select countries of interest
# vector countries of interest
SADCNames <- c("Angola", "Botswana", "Swaziland", "Comoros", "DR Congo", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Seychelles", "South Africa", "Tanzania", "Zambia","Zimbabwe")  

SADC_DVX_VAexp <- DVX_VAexp %>%
  filter(DVX_VAexp$V1 %in% SADCNames)
```

Comment: Have you tried the pivot_longer() function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `pivot_longer` as -

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(SADC_DVX_VAexp, cols = -V1, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'year'),
                    names_pattern = '(.*?)(\\d+)')

#   V1       year     DVX   VA_exp
#   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Angola   1990  416258. 1258915 
# 2 Angola   1991  446697. 1392318 
# 3 Angola   1992  597805. 1870753 
# 4 Angola   1993  499130. 1608752 
# 5 Angola   1994  655504. 2085250 
# 6 Angola   1995      NA  1521991 
# 7 Botswana 1990   56364.  247510 
# 8 Botswana 1991   54098.  247905.
# 9 Botswana 1992   58326.  260424.
#10 Botswana 1993   58460.  245404.
# … with 26 more rows
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
SADC_DVX_VAexp <- structure(list(V1 = c("Angola", "Botswana", "DRCongo", "Lesotho", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi"), DVX1990 = c(416258.3, 56364.31, 236784.5, 
6222.682, 79830.22, 51759.32), DVX1991 = c(446696.9, 54098.04, 
192829.6, 5691.562, 79074.5, 57607.13), DVX1992 = c(597805.1, 
58326.03, 191504.1, 7669.519, 91451.38, 56463.37), DVX1993 = c(499129.6, 
58459.56, 178502.7, 8340.936, 95090.82, 50866.98), DVX1994 = c(655503.9, 
64559.36, 198157, 8990.118, 110577.6, 50288.08), VA_exp1990 = c(1258915, 
247510, 417597.4, 63759.54, 325254.9, 205316.7), VA_exp1991 = c(1392318, 
247904.6, 330625.3, 59936.89, 320890.6, 244511.7), VA_exp1992 = c(1870753, 
260424.4, 316347.4, 68551.54, 370122.3, 233732.5), VA_exp1993 = c(1608752, 
245404.4, 291127.5, 59214.12, 395407.8, 210306.9), VA_exp1994 = c(2085250, 
259269.5, 317557.2, 54261.97, 456894.6, 217603.9), VA_exp1995 = c(1521991, 
303265.7, 395383.6, 55090.95, 541780.8, 255140.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```